# Javascript export function as a class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some code which is an export function...like this:

```
export default function somename(param, callback) {
  // code here
}
```

Can the above be chanced to a class? Unless its not recommended

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that you can't put a class there? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function accepts input and returns output. A class can have static members, both methods and properties, as well as be instantiated with the `new` keyword. If you had more specifics, it's possible we could see how a refactor could fit, but it's unlikely this makes sense since they serve different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class when you need state. If your function doesn't need state, you don't need a class.